# Swift Pass Multiple Parameters through Init

Tags: swift, class, initialization

I have a class with two initializers that I'm interested in passing information, title and description.

```
class CustomSearchResult {

    var description: String?
    var title: String?
    init(title: String) {
        self.title = title
    }
    init(description: String) {
        self.description = description
    }

}
```

Which later I reference in order to store this information into a custom search

```
customSearchResults.append(SearchResultType.customResult(result: CustomSearchResult(title: titleString!,description: descriptionString!)))
```

However, this produces an error "Cannot invoke initializer for type 'CustomSearchResult' with an argument list of type '(title: String, description: String)'"

Is there a way to pass both these initialized variables as described?

Comment: An init method can have multiple parameters, like any other Swift method ...

Comment: You may also want to consider making `CustomSearchResult` a `struct` instead of a `class`. Then you don't need any explicit initializers. You will automatically get one that takes the two values as parameters.

Comment: Unrelated, but if you're invoking this with `titleString!` and `descriptionString!`, do we infer that neither of these can be `nil`? If that is the case, they shouldn't be optionals in `CustomSearchResult` declaration. Also unrelated, but I would discourage the use of a property called `description`, because that name is used by `CustomStringConvertible` (and it is `String`, not `String?`). You might not be using that pattern right now, you but you may at some future date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create another initializer:

```
init(title: String?, description: String?) {
        self.title = title
        self.description = description
}
```

You may not need to use optionals as parameters, according to your needs...

```
init(title: String, description: String) {
        self.title = title
        self.description = description
}
```

Comment: If you just have the one initializer and that one initializer doesn't accept optional arguments, then there is no need for the properties to be optional either.